# I want the icons colour to be changed for 2 sec and them back to normal when click in bottomnavigation bar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I want to change clicked icon colour when we click on icon but after 2 seconds it should remove the focus colour.

only the icon should be focused on clicking for 2 seconds then it should come back to normal.

basically, When we click on icon it gets the selected item colour, but I want it to be removed after 2 second.

Please help in this

Any help will be appreciated,Thanks in advance

```
         child:Theme(
           data: ThemeData(
             splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
             splashColor: Color(0xFF009EFB),
             highlightColor: Color(0xFF009EFB),
           ),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
           backgroundColor: Color(0xFFDADADA),
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                showUnselectedLabels: true,
                showSelectedLabels: true,
                currentIndex: appStore.currentIndex,
                unselectedItemColor: textSecondaryColorGlobal,
                unselectedLabelStyle: secondaryTextStyle(),
                selectedLabelStyle: secondaryTextStyle(),
                selectedItemColor: textSecondaryColorGlobal,
                items: [
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: cachedImage('assets/hom.png', width: 20, height: 20, color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.color),
                      activeIcon: cachedImage('assets/hom.png', width: 20, height: 20, color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.color),
                      label: 'Home',
                    ),

                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: cachedImage('assets/shop.png', width: 20, height: 20, color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.color),
                    activeIcon: cachedImage('assets/shop.png', width: 20, height: 20, color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.color),
                    label: 'Shop',
                  ),

                                   
                ],
                onTap: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    appStore.currentIndex = index;
                    appStore.setIndex(index);

                  });

                  if(appStore.currentIndex == 0) {
                     webViewController!.loadUrl(urlRequest: URLRequest(url:                   }


                 else if(appStore.currentIndex == 1) {
                                      }
                                    
                }),
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `state` for button colour. Example for ElevatedButton:

```
class _MyWidget extends State<MyWidget> {
  Color color = Colors.blue;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: color),
      child: const Text('Hello, World!'),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() => {color = Colors.amber});
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          setState(() => {color = Colors.blue});
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```